# laravel 5 error 500 fresh install

Tags: laravel-5

Hello so i got back to laravel recently and want to put on my webserver but i get error 500 from a fresh installed laravel. though i havent done any modifying the code in the framework would be sweet if anyone has an idea whats going on in the changes to laravel from those settings i provide

error 500 and no logs in apache nor laravel

thanks in advance

htaccess file.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

conf file

```
    ServerName domain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/laravel/public/

    <Directory /var/www/laravel/public/>
                  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    LogLevel warn
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Linux os,you'll need to do the following

```
cd to_the_root_of_project - i.e. cd /var/www/html/LaravelProject

sudo chmod guo+w -R storage/
```

Comment: im using ubuntu 14 and i tried using that command but nothing happens